# dplyr - ratio of column

Tags: r, dplyr

Apologies if this is a repeat question. Can someone show me how to calculate the proportion in each column using dplyr? I listed input and output data below.

INPUT DATA

```
>sample_data
am     n
<dbl> <int>
 0    19
 1    13
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
>sample_data
am     n
<dbl> <int>
 0    0.59375
 1    0.40625
```

You can generate input data from the below code

```
sample_data <- mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% tally()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sample_data %>% 
mutate(Prop=n/sum(n))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get it as follows:

```
   sample_data %>% 
 mutate(Prop=n/sum(n)) %>% 
   select(-n)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     am  Prop
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0 0.594
2     1 0.406
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using summarize and was getting 1 as the answer. This has been troubling me from the past few hours